# How to bind the selected member of a ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox that is populated with objects of type `ProfileName`

```
Private Class ProfileName
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property File As String
    Public Property ProductVersion As String
End Class
```

These items are created added to the combo box after a deserialising a bunch of files and copying some of the values from the resulting objects:

```
    pcb.DisplayMember = "Name"
     For Each F As FileInfo In ProfileFiles
        Dim Reader As StreamReader = F.OpenText()
        Dim Serialize As Serializer = New Serializer()
        Dim SerializedData As String = Reader.ReadToEnd() 
        Dim P As Profile = Serialize.DesearializeObject(Of Profile)(SerializedData)

        If P.Type = Profile.ProfileType.Product Then
            Dim PN As ProfileName = New ProfileName()
            PN.File = F.Name
            PN.ProductVersion = P.ProductVersion
            PN.Name = P.ProductName & " - " & P.ProductVersion
            pcb.Items.Add(PN)
        End If
        Reader.Close()
    Next
```

Then if a user opens one of these files, the file will be again deserialised resulting in a Profile object with a 'ProductName' property that should match one of the items already on the ComboBox items list, so I'd like for the ComboBox to show that as the selected item.

i.e. 
-On form load the ComboBox is populated with all possible product names.
-When a profile file is opened the product that the profile uses is automatically selected in the ComboBox.

I've been playing with

```
ProductComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", CurrentProfile, "ProductName")
```

and permutations thereof, but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Since you are phyiscally adding the items to the CBO. I think you need to set the SelectedIndex to whatever. A much easier way to do it is to serialize a collection/list of Profile to one file all at once, then bind the list to the control as the DataSource

Comment: Is there another Type somewhere?  `Profile.ProfileType.Product` comes out of nowhere and looks like Shared/static refs.  Also, I assume this is JSon.NET (even though they spell `DesearializeObject` differently)?

Comment: @Plutonix `Profile.ProfileType.Product` looks like an enum to me.  OP: SelectedValue only works when you set the DataSource and ValueMember properties of the ComboBox.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, `Profile.ProfileType.Product` is an enum value and yes, it is Json.NET, the `DesearlialzeObject` is a typo, it should of course be `DeserializeObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant mix and match - put objects into the items collection and use the data binding methods/elements.  Databinding basics:

```
Public Class Profile
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property File As String
    Public Property ProductVersion As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, ProductVersion)
    End Function
End Class
```

The `ToString()` controls what will be displayed when you cant specify the property to display.  Note, these should be properties becaus mere Fields will be treated differently.

Then a container for them.  This will be the DataSource for the cbo.

```
Private Profiles As List(Of Profile)
...
' create instance of list and populate from where ever:
Profiles = New List(Of Profile)
Profiles.Add(New Profile With {.Name = "Default", .File = "foo",
            .ProductVersion = "1.0"})
Profiles.Add(New Profile With {.Name = "Ziggy", .File = "bat",
            .ProductVersion = "1.9.8"})
Profiles.Add(New Profile With {.Name = "Zoey", .File = "bar",
            .ProductVersion = "1.4.1"})
```

Rather than putting the Profile objects into the Items collection, bind the control to the List:

```
cboP.DataSource = Profiles
cboP.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

If you omit the property to display, `ToString()` will be shown (or `WindowsApp1.Profile` if you did not override it). Note: When using a DataSource you no longer add or delete from the control's `Items` collection - it will yell at you.  Instead manage the underlying source, your `List(Of Profile)` in this case.

To change the selection, for example to the one for "Ziggy":

```
Dim n As Int32 = Profiles.FindIndex(Function(f) f.Name = "Ziggy")
If n > -1 Then
    cboP.SelectedIndex = n
End If
```

You can also set `SelectedItem` after you find the `Profile` instead, but I tend to use index.  Even though the list is a new actor, serializing the entire thing is easy:

```
' serializing the List acts on all the profiles in it
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Profiles)
File.WriteAllText("C:\Temp\Profiles.json", json)
```

Read it back:

```
json = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\Profiles.json")
Dim newPs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Profile))(json)
```

Its a bit simpler than looping thru a set of files. `List(of T)` has a full set of methods and extensions to remove, sort, find etc so you should gain functionality over the items collection or array.

Alternatively, you could keep the one file per structure, but add the deserialized `Profile` objects to a `List(of Profile)` rather than the `Items` collection.

Comment: Hm. I had been trying to stay way from this to reduce having a collection that duplicates data that's in files. But now I think about it I see my program has nearly duplicated this idea anyway. So I'll try this and see how I get on. 
I do need the files to be separate though so that a user can work with a file that relates to a specific product away from my program. This was *part* of the idea behind using JSON, it's easy to read and type without using a special editor or program.
Thanks!

Comment: How can I bind the control such that it only shows profiles that have a certain type value? (the enum)
I'd rather not end up with multiple lists to bind, because theyre all profiles and some are parents or grandparents of others

Comment: Even if `Profiles` is mostly meta data about something else, that doesnt rule out also storing Product/Item data for your app.  That loop can still be disposed of though by a method on the Product/Item class to save itself.  Filtering would be a matter of running a linq query on the list (Profiles in the example). You might have an AllProfiles list and a FilteredProfiles which is a subset.